# Node JS(Express) connect-flash not working on redirects action

Tags: node.js, express, flash, message, connect-flash

I'm wondering why my connect-flash is not working.
I know connect-flash try to save message into session. 
So I declare session like this :

```
app.use(session());
```

Then I set up flash :

```
app.use(flash());
```

The problem is that when I using with connect-flash, it didn't show just set message after redirect action.

```
req.flash('flash_var', 'ok');
res.redirect('/mail/send');
```

I couldn't see any message at the '/mail/send' routers.

```
app.get('/mail/send', function(req, res) {
  res.render('mail/console', {
    console.log("flash : "+req.flash('flash_var'); // null
    message: req.flash('flash_var')
  });
});
```

The console message are printing null values, The previous step does not seem to send the value normally. Of course I didn't see any 'flash_var' at ejs page.

What's wrong with my code?

```
if(req.flash("flash_var") != ""){
  flash_var = req.flash("flash_var");
  console.dir("flash_var dir : "+req.flash("flash_var"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `req.flash('flash_name')` to get a flash message back. What you would do is `req.flash()['flash_name']`. In your case the message value in your res.render options object would be `req.flash()['flash_var']`. `req.flash()` is not an individual getter, it returns an object containing all flashes on the request object. The other way to use `req.flash()` is with two string inputs, like you did with `req.flash('flash_var', 'ok')`.